# Ease numbers in a certain range

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm trying to find an easing function taking in values from `0` to `π/4` and outputting values in the same range, which starts really slow and exponentially accelerates toward full speed.

Something like this:

[image]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Tyler, couldn't post the image due to rep.

Comment: Is an asymptote at $x=\pi/4$ acceptable or not?

Comment: @FrankMcGovern It would be, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a vertical asymptote at $x=\frac{\pi}4$ you may try something like :
$$f(x):=\frac{\pi}4\left(1-\sqrt{1-\left(\frac {4x}{\pi}\right)^4}\right)$$
[image: picture with vertical asymptot]

Should you prefer an exponential grow near $\frac{\pi}4$ then you may try :
$$\frac {\pi}4\left(\frac {4x}{\pi}\right)^4 e^{\frac {4x}{\pi}-1}$$
[image: exponential grow]

(you may 'tune' these propositions by replacing the power $4$ with other values and so on...)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot! May I ask how you found these, if that's not too long to explain? (Answer accepted anyhow.)

Comment: Thanks @user1728278 ! The first one is a deformation of the circle (turned upside down) i.e. start with $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, take $1-y$ and change $x$ and $y$ to feet your $\frac{\pi}4$ requirements. The second one starts with an horizontal asymptote at $0$ like $x^2$ (changed in $x^4$ because it is more 'pronounced'). This was multiplied by $e^x$ for faster evolution and the final scale change on $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

How about 
$$\large
f(x) = \frac{\pi}{4}2^{\frac{4x}{\pi}} -\frac{\pi}{4}\quad?
$$

Comment: The curve is in the spirit of what I'm looking for, but it's definitely not pronounced enough. Here's what I see for `x` between `0` and `π/4`: http://i.imgur.com/Tvgq6n3.png

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=k\frac{e^{-hk^2}-e^{-h(x-k)^2}}{e^{-hk^2}-1}.
$$

This function maps numbers from the range $[0,k]$ to $[0,k]$. Choosing $k=\frac{\pi}{4}$, the parameter $h$ can be changed to give the desired steepness. [Here](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIocGkvNCkvKChleHAoLTEwMCoocGkvNCleMiktMSkpKihleHAoLTEwMCoocGkvNCleMiktZXhwKC0xMDAqKHgtKHBpLzQpKV4yKSkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyIwLjAwNDQ2NzY5MjMwNzY5MjMzOSIsIjAuNzg0ODU5MDc2OTIzMDc3IiwiMC4wMDc5NjgwMDAwMDAwMDAxOTciLCIwLjc5MTY4OCJdfV0-) is a plot of the function for $h=100$.